# Integration Percy visual regression testing status check with Github

Tags: github

I am trying to integrate Percy.io, a visual regression testing tool with Github status check.

I have signed up for free account with [Percy](https://percy.io/) and paid Github version.

I wanted to setup status check with Percy with each pull request as below suggested at [percy doc on status check](https://docs.percy.io/docs/github)

[image]

I have integrated Percy in Github
[image]

Added rules in Github
[image]

but still don't see check on pull request.
[image]

Added same project in percy.io too
[image]

Any Idea what I am missing over here?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be specific without knowing more about your application, however one piece that seems to be missing from your setup is a CI/CD configuration.

Basically, you need a Continuous Integration service (such as Travis, Jenkins, CircleCI or others to trigger a build for your project so that percy can capture snapshots. Did you configure one?
See the documentation [here](https://go.percy.io/integrations/ci-cd).

Here an [example configuration](https://www.abahgat.com/blog/testing-static-sites/#running-tests-on-every-change-via-ci-services) for one of my projects. Note that how you set this up may differ if you use a different set of tools than what's in the article.